# -webkit-linear-gradient not working on chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I had below css for `mozilla firefox`

```
background: transparent -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #FED066, #FDB73D) repeat scroll 0% 0%;
```

But when I added below styles for `chrome`, `opera` and `IE`, none of them seems working. What's wrong with the below as it only works with `FF` and not with other browsers?

```
background: transparent -webkit-linear-gradient(center top , #FED066, #FDB73D) repeat scroll 0% 0%;
background: transparent -o-linear-gradient(center top , #FED066, #FDB73D) repeat scroll 0% 0%;
background: transparent -linear-gradient(center top , #FED066, #FDB73D) repeat scroll 0% 0%;
background: transparent -ms-linear-gradient(center top , #FED066, #FDB73D) repeat scroll 0% 0%;
```

I also tried with just `-webkit-gradient` instead of `-webkit-linear-gradient` for chrome atleast, but no luck.

Here is a **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/10jkk4vz/2/)**. If you view in `FF` it applies `gradient background` but not on other browsers.

Comment: The syntax for linear gradients has changed quite a lot over time, and different browsers (in different version) might interpret different versions, but ignore others. There are generators out there, that produce the necessary code, including vendor prefixes, automatically for you - so I suggest you go look for one of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer browsers don't implement vendor prefixes to use that features. You just need to use standard declaration too:

`center top` will not work in chrome browser.

Try this:

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FED066 0%, #FDB73D 100%);
```

I always use the [gradient-generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) tool to set gradient for cross browser implementation.

Comment: Yea.. It was useful indeed.. Thanks once again.. :)